# Selenium can't find element by xpath

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver, element

I've been working at this for some time now. I'm using Selenium and WebDriver version 2.33 (with all browsers). I'm using Java, which should be arbitrary. What I'm doing is simply find an element and hover over it, which I have done in earlier code. But for some reason, I can't get this one to work. I'm trying to get an element with this xpath, obtained by right-clicking the element in the HTML in Chrome and clicking "copy xpath":

```
//*[@id="highcharts-10"]/svg/g[7]/g/rect[1]
```

This is how I'm trying to get the element (due to "highcharts-10" dynamically changing):

```
//*[starts-with(@id, 'highcharts')]/svg/g[7]/g/rect[" + barOption + "]
```

barOption is inputting correctly (there are a bunch of bars that I'm trying to go through)

Here is my Java code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getWebDriver(), 5);
WebElement element;
WebDriver driver = getWebDriver();
By by = By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'highcharts')]/svg/g[7]/g/rect[" + barOption + "]");
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement elem = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
action.moveToElement(elem);
action.perform();
```

What am I doing incorrect here? I've tried using switchTo() statements, but there are no iframes that I can correctly switch to. Here is a picture the HTML because I can't get my hands on the actual text:

**UPDATED HTML LINK:**
http://i1250.photobucket.com/albums/hh527/dr4g1116/Capture_zps6e2bc1b9.png

Anyone have any suggestions for me? Please let me know what I'm doing wrong!

Thanks!!

Comment: give the `html` part here.. some important part has not been captured.

Comment: Just updated to show up to the HTML tag. I figured it wasn't relevant due to the fact that I've already obtained elements approximately down to this level before.

Comment: Can you share the code and HTML that did work ?

Comment: @amey are you referring to the other times where I referenced different things? Here is an xpath on that very same page that I accessed successfully:

`by = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"table_Table_monitor_reported_problems\"]/tbody/tr[" + row + "]/td[" + column + "]/div/div/span");`

This leads me to think that it might be the @starts-with that might be throwing me off.

Comment: Exactly. So looking at the id "highcharts-10", i assume that there are 9 more. Are you for sure that the xpath is picking `highcharts-10` and not say `highcharts-8` or `highcharts-7`?

Comment: @amey Unfortunately that's not how it works. The -X at the end of highcharts is dynamic and random at that. There's actually only one highcharts chart located on this website (would post a picture if not due to client data appearing there). Otherwise I would say that's a great suggestion.

Comment: Also, is `By by = By.xpath` finding an `element` or `elements`? If you can search by `elements`, try checking for the length of the array. And on traversing the array select the index you want to work with. Does this make sense?

Comment: @amey That line of code is trying to find one singular element at this point. The issue is that I can't find ANY element. Just times out without finding even one instance of that element.

Comment: @dr4g1116, I am saying try finding by element**s** for xpath `//*[starts-with(@id, 'highcharts')]/svg/`. How many elements are you returned with?

Comment: @amey Ah I see! Let me edit my code and figure that out!

Comment: @dr4g1116 read the `html` struture,and use `css`. Its looking good.

Comment: @amey Interesting. I'm getting no elements with the `//*[starts-with(@id, 'highcharts')]/svg/`. I mean I guess that just points to the fact that the selenium Java can't see the element at all, whether it just can't see it or the xpath expression itself is incorrectly formed, which doesn't seem to be the problem because I've used the start-with in EXACTLY the same manner I have here (I've checked it multiple times).

Comment: @dr4g1116, one more thing that you could use to debug is find element**s** by `css` using this `By.css('div[id^="highcharts"])`, what this says, is exactly what you do with xpath. I.e. `Id` starts_with

Comment: also whats the error you see? I mean at what step does it actually fail?

Comment: @amey It definitely stops at the line where it tries to find the element, then says that it can't find the element. I think I'll try a little bit more with CSS. I'm not super familiar with it, so it might be a struggle but it can be well worth it.

Comment: Also one other thing you can do to check is, in firefox firebug, inspect the element you are trying to interact with. If there HTML appears grayed out, it wont be visible to Selenium

Comment: @amey once again very interesting. Let me try that right away. Thank you for the suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Try as [`CSS Selectors`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) :

```
By by = By.css('div[id^="highcharts"] g[class^="highcharts"] > g > rec')
```

`g.class_name` I used,as that `<g>` tags class name is not visible. Replace that class name with the proper *class name*.

Comment: Unfortunately the ID "highcharts-24" is dynamic. The constant part of it is "highcharts-" which is why I was using the "starts-with" to begin with. How can I get the same effect using CSS selectors? Thanks for the response! :)

Comment: @dr4g1116 `"highcharts-24"` total is dynamic. or any part?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what your asking. Are you saying "highcharts-24" is dynamic in the CSS selector you posted?

Comment: @dr4g11164 no.. I am talking about does `highcharts` will always be there in the `ID` ? or full `ID` is dynamic?

Comment: "highcharts-" will always be in the ID. It's the number that comes after it that is dynamic.

Comment: Awesome. I'll give it a shot. One more question - how would I handle multiple "rect" nodes? They are denoted rect[x] in xpath, just not sure about CSS. Cheers!!

Comment: @dr4g1116 I have given a link,I hope you will get their your way out. :))

Comment: Gr. The <g> you're referring to doesn't have a className. (Just looked at this now). Any other suggestions?

Comment: @dr4g1116 Can you give the `html` part of that `<g>`?

Comment: `<g zIndex="1" transform="translate(274,466) rotate(90) scale(-1,1)" width="114" height="456" clip-path="url(https://loyalty.gfk.com/?P=j8JUYsD89gzQZ4wL8T9Q&amp;GetDashboard=1&amp;UseMinified=1&amp;t=1371481453&amp;DashboardID=24&amp;Type=index#highcharts-25)">` There you go!

Comment: @dr4g1116 which of the attribute value of the `<g>` is fixed?

Comment: that's a good question. I didn't program the HTML and haven't really noticed any of that being dynamic. But hypothetically say zIndex is fixed...?

Comment: @dr4g1116 Ok can you tell if the `<g>` tag count is always fixed or you always want to get the last `<g>` adjacent `<rec>`? I need that. Say you have 5 `<g>` and you would always need to reach the 3rd <g>.Is there any chance ?

Comment: Luckily it's the only <g> at that level. So it's the first and only <g> I would need to get. The rect[x] nodes under it are what I would need multiple of.

Comment: It didn't work! :( Darn. Just want you to know I really appreciate the time you've spent with me. Upvoting for suggesting CSS selectors (which unfortunately I know nothing about...!)

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to give a slight update on this. It seems selenium can't see past the SVG tags, so with that being said, I need to find a method to see around them...I will report back if I'm able to find out how.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

From your discussion with Amey i deduced that you have only one highchart. so try directly searching for element "highcharts-tracker" using classname i.e By.ClassName("highcharts-tracker") and then hover on this element itself. This would exactly do what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I'm trying to hover over multiple points on the chart (It's a bar graph and each bar has a different hover over value.) So if I just hover over the chart itself, it won't get the desired effect. Thanks much for the suggestion!!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry just seeing your comment on my earlier answer. 
You can get the values for each bar in barchart by following way:

```
var barValues = new List<string>(); 
var actions = new Actions(webDriver); //webDriver is instance of selenium WebDriver.
var chartSeriesGroup = webDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("highcharts-series-group"));
var chartSeries = chartSeriesGroup.FindElement(By.ClassName("highcharts-series"));
var rectTags = chartSeries.FindElements(By.TagName("rect")); //To get all bars in barchart.

foreach (var rect in rectTags)
{
   actions.MoveToElement(rect).Perform(); //Hover mouse on bar.
   var trendMarkers = webDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("highcharts-tooltip"));
   barValues.Add(trendMarkers.Text); //Storing tooltip value of bar for later use.
}
```

I am using same method in my current project for getting values of bars in bar chart. Hope this will help you.

Note : If tooltip for bar shows other information e.g.name etc along with value then you need to write logic for extracting the value part from the complete information stored in barValues.